# Focus order in chrome extension popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, focus

Today I made my first Chrome extension and it's running good.

This extension is very simple it permits to the user to create a list of vocabulary in french and dutch.

When the pop-up opens the first field has the focus because I use .focus() for that. That's OK.
But when I press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, the focus disappears. I don't know where it goes. 
If I click on the first field then I can fly to the second field and after to the submit button.
I dont want to click on the field. My goal is to use this extension only with the keyboard.

I try to solve this with 'tabindex' but it did not work.

Here the code (simplified) of my **`popup.html`**

```
<div>
<form action="#">
    <div><h1>Vocabulaire / Woordenschat</h1></div>
    <div><label for="fr">FR:</label><input type="text"   id="fr"></div>
    <div><label for="nl">NL:</label><input type="text"  id="nl"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" id="enregistrer" value="Sturen"></div>
</form>
```

I use Chrome version Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Any Idea ?

Comment: Can you share focus related code for **`popup.html`**

Comment: finally it seems that it is a bug of Chrome. Information here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111660 Thank you for your answer.